# Multiple object count

Tags: python, opencv

I want to count the moving particles passing through the video in python opencv. For this, I find the object's centroids in the current and previous frames.

What I want to do is as follows:
If the center point in the previous frame is less than a certain pixel value and the center point in the current frame is greater than this value, increase the counter by one.

For example, there are two objects in the frame: center_points_prev_frame [541, 233] has two center points, then it became center_points_cur_frame [563, 261]. if 541<250 and 563>250, increment the counter by 1. In addition if 233<250 and 261>250 increment the counter. Since the coordinates in these arrays belong to different objects, I wanted to compare them among themselves.
Can you help me how to use this in my code?

```
for cnt in contours:
        x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        cx = int(x + x + w) // 2
        center_points_cur_frame.append((cx))

    for i in range(len(center_points_cur_frame)) and range(len(center_points_prev_frame)):

        if (center_points_cur_frame[i]>250) and (center_points_prev_frame[i]<250):
            counter += 1
            print("count", counter)
```

Comment: `range(len(center_points_cur_frame)) and range(len(center_points_prev_frame))` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(center_points_cur_frame)) and range(len(center_points_prev_frame)):
```

is equivalent to just

```
for i in range(len(center_points_cur_frame)):
```

because all `range` objects are truthy. So if `center_points_cur_frame` is longer than `center_points_prev_frame` you'll get an error when you get past the length of the latter list.

I think you're trying to use the range of indexes of the shorter list. You could use `range(min(len(center_points_cur_frame), len(center_points_prev_frame)))` to get this minimum length.

But a simpler way to iterate over two lists in parallel is to use the `zip()` function. This will stop when it reaches the end of the shorter list.

```
for cur, prev in zip(center_points_cur_frame, center_points_prev_frame):
    if cur > 250 and prev < 250:
        counter += 1
        print("count", counter)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It solved my error. Actually, that's what I wanted to do: For example, there are two objects in the frame: center_points_prev_frame [541, 233] has two center points, then it became center_points_cur_frame [563, 261].  if 541<250 and 563>250, increment the counter by 1. In addition if 233<250 and 261>250 increment the counter. Since the coordinates in these arrays belong to different objects, I wanted to compare them among themselves.

Comment: I don't know anything about image processing, so I'm not sure I can help you there.

Comment: Okey thank you very much for your help

Comment: I edit my question

Comment: My answer is for fixing the index error. Don't change your question to a different problem.